# Magento 2 : I have add new field to cusotmer group but value not save

Tags: magento2, forms, adminform, custom-field, addfield

I have add new custom fields to customer group (**`adminhtml`**) but value not save.

For **add new field into customer group** I have override below file:

> Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Form.php

```
$form = $this->getForm();
$fs = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');
//$groupId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry( RegistryConstants::CURRENT_GROUP_ID);
$fs->addField(
    'display_status',
     'select',
     [
         'label' => __('Status'),
         'title' => __('Status'),
         'name' => 'display_status',
         'required' => true,
         'options' => [
             '1' => __('Enabled'), 
             '0' => __('Disabled')],
         ]
);
$this->setForm($form);
```

Is there any need to override any model for save value?

Please guide me 
thanks

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Did you add table to save your data? If yes please share that code

Comment: yes, i have add field in customer group table @NehaRaval

Comment: i am using magento 2.1.3 version

Comment: @NavinBhudiya Did you able to save value?

Comment: @SureshChikani yes it was fixed

Comment: @NavinBhudiya If you can add those code, that would be great. I face the same issue, your help might be resolved my issue. Thank You,